# Kafka Connect not consuming from Partition 0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am facing a weird issues where Kafka connect is not consuming data from one of the topics where we dump our logging data

The topic initially had only 1 partition and has overall size of 250MB+. I increase the partitions of the topic to 5 and now I can see rest all partitions getting consumed but not the original partition 0

```
GROUP                        TOPIC                 PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                    HOST            CLIENT-ID
connect-request-log-elk-sink request-log           0          6               281294          281288          connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-0-ed4062a0-8712-46f5-939a-f0b783c3352c /XXX  connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-0
connect-request-log-elk-sink request-log           1          9882            16840           6958            connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-1-8f4a0ddf-7c91-4cde-93ab-05c5bf1deb2a /XXX  connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-1
connect-request-log-elk-sink request-log           3          9994            16918           6924            connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-3-83d0863e-dbc5-47ec-b240-b0e8eacbcb94 /XXX   connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-3
connect-request-log-elk-sink request-log           4          9744            16628           6884            connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-4-2c190184-5787-4b6d-91f4-16dd71fc6ea5 /XXX   connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-4
connect-request-log-elk-sink request-log           2          10885           16687           5802            connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-2-5e2c46c5-4e43-4a4c-af13-07d133e39038 /XXX   connector-consumer-request-log-elk-sink-2
```

The offset for partition 0 was stuck at 1, so I manually increased offset for the consumer by 1 multiple times to see if that helps move the topic. But that didn't change much

below is kafka connect config fog the same

```json
{
    "connection.url": "http://xxx:9200",
    
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type.name": "request-log-elk-sink",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
    "auto.create.indices.at.start": "false",
    "read.timout.ms": "10000",
    "tasks.max": "5",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "retry.backoff.ms": "5000",
    "transforms": "InsertTimestamp",
    "transforms.InsertTimestamp.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
    "transforms.InsertTimestamp.timestamp.field": "eventTime",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
    "max.buffered.records": "1000",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "topics": "request-log,request-exception-log",
    "batch.size": "500",
    "max.in.flight.requests": "2",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "IGNORE",
    "flush.timeout.ms": "600000",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "request-log-dead-letter",
    "name": "request-log-elk-sink",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "linger.ms": "1000"
}
```

Can anyone throw any light on why only one partition in Kafka will have a problem? I am able to view all data using `kafka-ui` and also able to dump all data using `kafkacat`

Comment: Do you have access to the logs of Kafka Connect when the connector starts? There seems to exist a consumer instance connected to the partition 0 according to the trace you gave (it has a consumer id at least), so we should see stuff like "resetting consumer offset to..." or something like that in the log. Maybe there's some more clue there as well about what's going on?

Comment: Log is available at https://pastebin.com/kyY64Nm1, couldn't find anything like resetting

Comment: I think it's line 1757: `Setting offset for partition request-log-0 to the committed offset Fe    tchPosition{offset=6...` , which also corresponds to the offset 6 you have above. Is anything fishy happening after that to `request-log-elk-sink|task-0` ?

Comment: No, its not moving, no errors in kafka connect. You have the full log in the pastebin

Comment: Are all tasks running in the `/status` endpoint? Have you tried to call `/restart` on the task that is assigned to partition 0?

Comment: Yes, that has already been tried. All the `/status` is running with no errors